# How to understand includes in Rails with ajax-datatables-rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatable

I'm using `ajax-datatables-rails` and want to use an associated model in the datatable file, I want to use the `include()` method. However, it's not that simple. According to https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails, their `include()` example is extremely complicated and goes far beyond what I'm trying to do.

I have a model called `Page` and one called `Book` for example, and I just simply want to use `Pages.include(:book)` so that I can call `page.book` in my view later on.

How can I accomplish that using their scenario? Here's what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
# app/datatables/example_datatable.rb
  # Allow the use of helpers in JSON response.
  def_delegators :@view, :link_to, :book_path

  def view_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    # or in aliased_join_table.column_name format
    @view_columns ||= {
      # id: { source: "User.id", cond: :eq},
      # name: { source: "User.name"}

      position: { source: "Page.position"},
      book_name: { source: "Page.book.book_name"},
    }
  end

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      {
        # example:
        # id: record.id,
        # name: record.name
        position: record.position,
        book_name: link_to("#{record.book.book_name}", book_path(record), remote: true),
      }
    end
  end

  private

  def get_raw_records
    # insert query here
    Page.includes(:book).references(:book).distinct
  end
```

If I just left it at `Pages.includes(:book)` then I get an error in my datatable **only** when I attempt to use the search/filter textbox. Otherwise, things are displayed just fine.

The error that I get states:

> Unknown column 'pages.book' in 'where clause'

In their example, they stated that `references(:related_model)` is in here, but I'm not exactly sure how to swing it using my simple one-model-association.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What did you observe? what was the error message and how did you see it?

Comment: I saw the error through the console. It still gave me the error that the guide stated it would give: Unknown column 'pages.book' in 'where clause' as if it doesn't know how to access book. I'll update this with the rest of my code as well.

Comment: So, can you try doing this: `Page.includes(:book).references(:book).distinct.to_sql` and `Page.includes(:book).references(:book).to_sql` and see what it says? sometimes this makes it obvious what is missing...

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails it looks like you might need to put `Book.name` into your `@view_columns` instead of `Page.book.name` and use `joins(:book)` instead of `include/references` ?

Comment: Wow, so that did the trick @TarynEast. Thank you a lot!!!!!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [ajax-datatables-rails README](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails) it looks like you might need to:

1. put `Book.name` into your `@view_columns` instead of `Page.book.name`
2. use `joins(:book)` instead of `include/references`